# How to filter on multiple attributes in XMLStarlet?

Tags: xml, bash, xpath, xmlstarlet

For example, given:

```
<fruit>
   <banana source='Ecuador' category='I'>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
   </banana>
   <banana source='Costa Rica' category='I'>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
   </banana>
</fruit>
```

Say I want to change

```
<banana source='Costa Rica' category='I'>
```

to

```
<banana source='Costa Rica' category='II'>
```

or its quantity to 2, how would I reference it if I want to filter on both the source and the initial category value?

---

I'm trying to do the following:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "/fruit/banana[@source='Ecuador' @category='I']/quantity" -v 2
```

...but this results in a syntax error, as follows:

```
Invalid predicate: /fruit/banana[@source='Ecuador' @category='I']/quantity
Invalid expression: /fruit/banana[@source='Ecuador' @category='I']/quantity
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/xmlstarlet.pdf)?  Have you tried any of the command options? Can you show what you've tried and explain what didn't work?

Comment: Yes, I read the documentation, found references and examples with only one attribute.

I was trying to do something like: xmlstarlet ed -u "/fruit/banana[@source='Ecuador' @category='I']/quantity" -v 2 example.xml

But it gives me:

Invalid predicate: /fruit/banana[@source='Ecuador' @category='I']/quantity
Invalid expression: /fruit/banana[@source='Ecuador' @category='I']/quantity

Comment: Should probably be tagged `xpath`.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs You're right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After quite a bit of trial and error, reached a solution:

I need to close and re-open [] with the next attribute. For example:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "/fruit/banana[@source='Ecuador'][@category='I']/quantity" -v 2 example.xml
```

And would correctly output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<fruit>
  <banana source="Ecuador" category="I">
    <quantity>2</quantity>
  </banana>
  <banana source="Costa Rica" category="I">
    <quantity>1</quantity>
  </banana>
</fruit>
```

Edit: also works:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "/fruit/banana[@source='Ecuador' and @category='I']/quantity" -v 2 example.xml
```

Comment: That's one approach, yes.

Comment: ...and you just found the other approach I was preparing to add as a separate answer. :)